# Mixpanel-Shopify Integration via GTM

Tags: shopify, google-tag-manager, mixpanel

I have been trying to integrate mixpanel into my shopify store using gtm for quite a while now, but ive run into an issue. Mixpanel is not storing the mp_ cookie related to distinct id, resulting in every event passed to mixpanel being assigned a new distinct id. I have a self hosted demo site where i implemented mixpanel via gtm in the same way and i can see an mp_ cookie storing the distinct id in the developer tools. the first screenshot is of the cookie on the working site and the second is of the shopify store.

[mp_cookie on the site where its correctly implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M196P.png)

[no mp_ cookie on the shopify store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoBtJ.png)

all implementation has been done in the exactly same way as both sites. I have also checked for any errors related to this on console. Im a beginner to web dev so i have limited knowledge in figuring out the issue.